# How to set seconds in jQuery date time picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker, timepicker

How to set the seconds in [Jquery date time picker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), It will be show on
[image]

```
format: 'd/m/Y g:i A', //Ex:01/01/2017 10:00 AM
```

Here, I add the "s"

```
format: 'd/m/Y g:i:s A', //Ex:01/01/2017 10:00:06 AM, if change the time at 12:35 PM it will be shown as 12:35:06 PM
```

How can I add the seconds?

Comment: It doesn't look like this plugin supports seconds

Comment: you will use the  moment.js library this will help.

Comment: Dont think it supports seconds. if it does then there will be hundreds of time selection.